# Get array index of matching query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing records in Elasticsearch as:

```
"mappings": {
    "en": {
      "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Where each elasticsearch record is actually many records bundled into one by having the `id` field an array of ids `[id1, id2, id3, ...]` and the `text` field its respective text `['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3', ...]`, so a `POST` would look something like:

```
POST my-index/en
{
  "id": ["{doc1-ID}", "{doc2-ID}"],
  "text": ["document 1 text goes here", "document 2 text goes here"]
}
```

And I'm running a search for text in the `text` field, and this all ok except I need the matching documents corresponding `id` value. I can do this within the app logic itself by iterating through each array item, but that is very costly and inefficient since each Elasticsearch record will be near the max size of ~2GB, so storing that in memory while I search through it all is simply not an option. I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the array index of the matching text from the `text` array field, so that I can grab it's respective `id`. Is there a way to get the array's index of the matching text using some kind of Elasticsearch script?

**NOTE:** I'm storing my documents in this seemingly convoluted way for a very good reason, I realize it would obviously be much easier to have 1 record per elasticsearch record, as it's designed to be; but this will not work for my requirements.

Comment: In short, I don't think there is a way to do what you want.  If each ES document that you're uploading is close to 2GB you're going to have terrible performance all around and you should probably consider a tool other than ElasticSearch that is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Good point about the size and performance; I suppose my only option is to reduce the size and iterate the data manually.

Comment: ES is built to search hundreds of millions (or more) small documents, that's what it's great it.  So if you can break everything down and put each element in the array into it's own document then ES will do great for you.

Comment: You may save space by bulking them into 1, but the trade off is that you won't be able to search them as efficiently.  So it really all depends on your use case.  Is it more important to save space or search faster?  ES is build to handle 10 billion documents w/o breaking a sweat.